# proof $x \equiv a \mod{n} $, $x \equiv b \mod{m}$

Tags: number-theory

proof that the congruences.

$$x \equiv a \mod{n} $$ 
 $$x \equiv b \mod{m}$$

have the same solution if and only if   $ gcd ( n , m ) | a-b $  ;  also if you have solution , show that is single mod $icm(n,m).$

my work!!

$$gcd(m,n)|m.n$$

$$x \equiv a \mod{n} $$  $$x \equiv b \mod{m}$$
then 
 $$x-b \equiv 0 \mod{gcd(m,n)}$$

i dont know how to proof the reciprocal and show that is single mod $icm(n,m).$

Comment: What does $icm$ mean?

Comment: least common multiple

Comment: You haven't seemed to have finished the first part.

Comment: why??,,, then how do i make it?

Comment: +1 for a question that has mathjax and effort shown. That is a rare thing nowadays.